# Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetchAll()

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Guys i am trying to do a webservice for uni project. Everything seems ok untill i run the code and get this error  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetchAll() on null . This is the code can anyone please tell me what is wrong with it?

```
<?php
header("Content-type: application/json");
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=user;", "user", "pass");
$loc = $_GET["location"];
$type = $_GET["type"];
if(isset($_GET["location"]) && isset($_GET["type"]))
{
    $result = $conn->query("Select * from resit_accommodation where location='$loc' and type='$type'")
}
else if (isset($_GET["location"]))
{
    $result = $conn->query("Select * from resit_accommodation where location='$loc'");
}
else if (isset($_GET["type"]))
{
    $result = $conn->query("Select * from resit_accommodation where location='$type'");
}
$rows = $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo json_encode($rows);
?>
```

Comment: If none of the `if` conditions are true, you never set `$result`.

Comment: You also are open to SQL injections. You should parameterize the parameters you are passing in.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using PDO you should be using [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) with placeholder values and supply any user data as separate arguments. In this code you have potentially severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). Never use string interpolation or concatenation and instead use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and never put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or any user data directly in your query. Refer to [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) for general guidance and advice.

Answer (score 3):

If neither of the `$_GET` parameters is set, you never set `$result` to anything, so you'll get an error if you try to use it.

You should also use a prepared statement rather than substituting variables, to prevent SQL injection.

```
<?php
header("Content-type: application/json");
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=user;", "user", "pass");
$stmt = null;
if(isset($_GET["location"]) && isset($_GET["type"]))
{
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("Select * from resit_accommodation where location= :loc and type= :type");
    $stmt->execute(['loc' => $_GET['location'], 'type' => $_GET['type']]);
}
elseif (isset($_GET["location"]))
{
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("Select * from resit_accommodation where location= :loc");
    $stmt->execute(['loc' => $_GET['location']]);
}
elseif (isset($_GET["type"]))
{
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("Select * from resit_accommodation where location= :type");
    $stmt->execute(['type' => $_GET['type']]);
}
if ($stmt) {
    $rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
} else {
    $rows = [];
}
echo json_encode($rows);
?>
```